# Google search in grails application

Tags: grails, google-search

I am creating one web application in GRAILS framework.In that I want to implement google search feature.Can we implement this feature? If we can, How to implement this feature in grails application?

Can anyone provide help on this?

Thanks...

Comment: You're looking for a piece of eyewear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the [Google AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).